# Why does PHP call __set() after unset()ing declared typed property?

Tags: php, php-7.4

(Edited this question, the old version quoted the wrong version of the RFC.)

The [RFC for typed properties](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2) in PHP says that "If a typed property is `unset()`, then it returns to the uninitialized state." However, in PHP 7.4 (at least up to 7.4.5), it does appear to behave differently when the class implements `__set()`, and thus it's not exactly like the (original) uninitialized state. The magic function is not called when the uninitialized property is set for the first time, but it is (unexpectedly) called when the property is set again after having been unset. [Example code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8408b7816441ad7ce0dafcd583e269492d2484a6).

```
<?php

class X {
    public int $y;
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo "__set($name, $value) called";
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

$x = new X();
$x->y = 42; // Prints nothing, as expected.
unset($x->y);
$x->y = 43; // Prints `__set(y, 43) called`.
```

Am I overlooking something? Is this a bug in how PHP currently implements `unset()` for typed properties? Or should `__set()` even be called when an uninitialized typed property is set for the first time?

Comment: Think it is part of - *When a normal objects property is unset, it will result in the invocation of magic get when subsequently accessed...* (in the RFC)

Comment: That is about magic _get_, whereas my problem is with magic _set_. I'm not sure where exactly you got that sentence from, but from the link posted by Progman: "If a typed property is in uninitialized state, either because it has not yet been initialized, or because it has been explicitly unset(), then reads from this property will invoke the __get() method if it exists, consistently with the behavior of ordinary properties." So that sentence's intention is that the original uninitialized state and the state after unset() are equivalent.

Comment: Here's a different angle at the same problem: Right after `$x = new X()`, _reading_ from `$x->y` will call `__get()`, but writing to it will _not_ call `__set()`, which is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why?**

For the purpose of lazy initialization patterns.

> If a typed property is unset(), then it returns to the uninitialized state. While we would love to remove support for the unsetting of properties, this functionality is currently used for lazy initialization by Doctrine

So in PHP 8 they may forbid unsetting of declared properties, after providing some alternative mechanism for lazy initialization.

Comment: So, essentially you're saying that the current behavior might be weird, but it doesn't matter because I should be writing my application without that `unset()` to begin with (to be ready for PHP8 or just generally)? I guess that works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Magic getters/setters only trigger for non existing properties. Quote: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set -> `__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible (protected or private) or non-existing properties.`.

So in your example, at first the public variables does exist. After unset, the public variable does not exist/unintialized and magic getter/setter come into place.

I think this behaviour is still wrong because the property exist but it is uninitialized. Should be maybe a bug report?